# Flutter:How to remove elevation from ExpansionPanelList?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was trying to list dropdown like widget, but luckily found the expansion panel list widget to get my desired UX to feel.

So, I am using ExpansionPanelList in my flutter app, but don't require the default elevation/border-shadow it comes with.

I have no idea how to remove it, so as to make it look part of the body rather than an elevated container.

Currently looking like this:

[image: mock]

Following is my code:

```
class _PracticetestComp extends State<Practicetest> {
  var listofpracticetest;
  List<Item> _data = [
    Item(
      headerValue: 'Previous Question Papers',
      expandedValue: '',
    )
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffF8FDF7),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffF8FDF7), // status bar color
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          elevation: 0.0,
          leading: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 17),
            child: RawMaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
              },
              child: new Icon(
                Icons.keyboard_backspace,
                color: Colors.red[900],
                size: 25.0,
              ),
              shape: new CircleBorder(),
              elevation: 4.0,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          // height: 200,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[

                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                      child: Theme(
                          data: Theme.of(context)
                              .copyWith(cardColor: Color(0xffF8FDF7)),
                          child: _buildPanelPreviousPapers()))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildPanelPreviousPapers() {
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(item.headerValue),
            );
          },
          body: Container(

            child: ListTile(
              leading: Text(
                'Alegbra',
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),

              ),
            ),
          ),
          isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}

// stores ExpansionPanel state information
class Item {
  Item({
    this.expandedValue,
    this.headerValue,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded;
}
```

Comment: Use this: ExpansionPanelList(
      elevation: 0,

Answer (score 8):

wrap your entire expansion widget child inside **Material widget** and change the elevation based on expansion child is expanded or not with method

```
   Material(
        elevation: isSelected ? 4 : 0,
        child: ExpansionTile(
         onExpansionChanged:(value){
                            isSelected=value;
                            setState(){};
                                   },

         title: getExpantionTitle(context),
          children: getChildrentList(),
              ),
            ),
        ),
```

in case if you don't like divider in ExpansionTile tile do some thing like this

```
        final theme = Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: 
        Colors.transparent);
     //use as a child 
 child:Theme(data: theme, child: ExpansionTile(...));
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add this line:

```
ExpansionPanelList(
      elevation: 0, // this line
      expansionCallback: ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

First, it isn't recommended to not use elevation for `ExpansionPanelList` according to Material design spec.

However, if you really want to do that, there are 2 solutions for you, either you create your own custom `ExpansionPanelList`, or get ready to add couple of lines to the source file. I'm providing you the latter solution.

1. Open `expansion_panel.dart` file, go to the `build()` method of `_ExpansionPanelListState` and make following changes

   ```
   return MergeableMaterial(
     hasDividers: true,
     children: items,
     elevation: 0, // 1st add this line
   );
   ```
2. Now open `mergeable_material.dart` file, navigate to `_paintShadows` method of `_RenderMergeableMaterialListBody` class and make following changes:

   ```
   void _paintShadows(Canvas canvas, Rect rect) {

     // 2nd add this line
     if (boxShadows == null) return;

     for (final BoxShadow boxShadow in boxShadows) {
       final Paint paint = boxShadow.toPaint();
       canvas.drawRRect(kMaterialEdges[MaterialType.card].toRRect(rect), paint);
     }
   }
   ```

---

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately ExpansionPanelList elevation hardcoded, but you can make same widget with [ExpansionTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html), check this dartpad example.

https://dartpad.dev/0412a5ed17e28af4a46f053ef0f7a5c2

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way I can add my stying to the on click tab header/title entry?
Also, is it possible to add some text left to the v-shaped arrow in the header/title entry

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap it in a `ClipRect`.

```dart
  Widget _buildPanelPreviousPapers() {
    final panel = ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(item.headerValue),
            );
          },
          body: Container(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Text(
                'Alegbra',
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),

              ),
            ),
          ),
          isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
    return ClipRect(child: panel);
  }
```

To alter the default card background color add a Theme override:

```dart
    return ClipRect(
      child: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(cardColor: Colors.pink),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set `elevation` in the constructor (default value is 2), perhaps this is a recent API change:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList/ExpansionPanelList.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, [now](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/123971):

```dart
ExpansionPanelList(
      materialGapSize: 0,
      ...
```