# How to make the font of an expansion tile header bigger, when expanding? flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

As the question already tells I want to make this header bigger, when a tile is opened[image]
, how can I achieve a such behaviour?

This is the header code: I think that for that the bolean is needed that holds the value if the card is expanded, The boolean name is `isExpanded`

```
      children: infos.map<ExpansionPanel>((Info info) {
    return ExpansionPanel(
        headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(info.headerValue),
          );
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Replace your `headerBuilder` with this:

```
headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) => ListTile(
  title: Text(
    'Header 1',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30), // This is all you needed.
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks you! Can I ask you another question? You already answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463999/flutterhow-to-remove-elevation-from-expansionpanellist?answertab=votes#tab-top it didn't work for me, but I can not comment under your answer (lack of Reputation) to ask it you there

Comment: @Nikita You're welcome. In that answer, I made the changes in the source file (which I'm sure must have been updated in the latest Flutter version). As I said there, you shouldn't remove the elevation.

Comment: Even though Im sure that you have your reasons to not recommend it I still want to get rid of the elevation part with that method >,<, that's why I was wondering if there exists an updated version for this method

Comment: @Nikita There was another answer in the post where `Material` was used with `0` elevation, did you try that?

Comment: Yeah but was too incompetent, if I understood it correctly the existing expansion panel was changed through an expansion tile & then wrapped with material  & this line was added elevation: isSelected ? 4 : 0. Is this the crucial part of his answer, because I didn't quiet get all the other code that followed & therefore haven't succeeded in implementing, your answer seemed compared to that so simple